# Unity: How to Change App Icon Dynamically Without Duplication

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, appicon

I am developing a feature to change the app icon in my Android app. However, I am facing an issue where the app icon is duplicated in all cases except when changing the default icon.

Desired Behavior:

When the app icon is changed, only one icon should be displayed without any duplication.

Problem Description:

I am using the LauncherIcons class to change the app icon and have tried various options to set the icon. I have also cleared the cache and rebooted the device, but the issue persists.

Request for Help:

How to solve the app icon duplication issue?
How to change the app icon without duplication?
Any relevant code or configuration information?

Thank you in advance for your help.

[Select Immediately After Installation and Main Activity](https://imgur.com/a/GssXN7w)

[Select OneLauncher Alias (change app icon)](https://imgur.com/a/HUZMgob)

MainActivity in Android Studio Project:

```java
public void ChangeIcon(Context context, String[] iconList, String iconType) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();

        ComponentName mainComponentName = getComponentName();


        int actionType = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < iconList.length; i++) {
            if (iconList[i].equals(iconType)) {
                actionType = PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED;
            } else {
                actionType = PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED;
            }

            String packageName = String.format("%s.%s", getClass().getPackage().getName(), iconList[i]);
            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, packageName);
            manager.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(context, String.format("%s.%s", getClass().getPackage().getName(), iconList[i])),
                    actionType, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        }
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml in Android Studio Project:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">

        </activity>

        <activity-alias
            android:name=".OneLauncherAlias"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/testicon_1"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity-alias>

        <activity-alias
            android:name=".TwoLauncherAlias"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/testicon_2"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity-alias>

        <activity-alias
            android:name=".ThreeLauncherAlias"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/testicon_3"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity-alias>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

AppIconChange in Unity Project:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button _toast;
    public Button _main;
    public Button _appIcon01;
    public Button _appIcon02;
    public Button _appIcon03;

    private AndroidJavaObject activityContext = null;
    private AndroidJavaClass javaClass = null;
    private AndroidJavaObject javaClassInstance = null;
    private string[] IconTypeArr = { "MainActivity", "OneLauncherAlias", "TwoLauncherAlias", "ThreeLauncherAlias" };

    private void Awake()
    {
        using (AndroidJavaClass activityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
        {
            activityContext = activityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        }

        using (javaClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.test.testApp.player.MainActivity"))
        {
            if (javaClass != null)
            {
                javaClassInstance = javaClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("instance");
            }
        }

        _toast.onClick.AddListener(OnClickToast);
        _main.onClick.AddListener(OnClickChangeAppIcon_Main);
        _appIcon01.onClick.AddListener(OnClickChangeAppIcon_1);
        _appIcon02.onClick.AddListener(OnClickChangeAppIcon_2);
        _appIcon03.onClick.AddListener(OnClickChangeAppIcon_3);
    }

    private void OnClickToast()
    {
        javaClassInstance.Call("ShowToast", activityContext, "테스트 토스트 메세지 출력 ^^");
    }

    private void OnClickChangeAppIcon_Main()
    {
        javaClassInstance.Call("ChangeIcon", activityContext, IconTypeArr, "MainActivity");
        javaClassInstance.Call("ShowToast", activityContext, "기본 앱 아이콘으로 변경");
    }

    private void OnClickChangeAppIcon_1()
    {
        javaClassInstance.Call("ChangeIcon", activityContext, IconTypeArr, "OneLauncherAlias");
        javaClassInstance.Call("ShowToast", activityContext, "커스텀 아이콘 1번으로 변경");
    }

    private void OnClickChangeAppIcon_2()
    {
        javaClassInstance.Call("ChangeIcon", activityContext, IconTypeArr, "TwoLauncherAlias");
        javaClassInstance.Call("ShowToast", activityContext, "커스텀 아이콘 2번으로 변경");
    }

    private void OnClickChangeAppIcon_3()
    {
        javaClassInstance.Call("ChangeIcon", activityContext, IconTypeArr, "ThreeLauncherAlias");
        javaClassInstance.Call("ShowToast", activityContext, "커스텀 아이콘 3번으로 변경");
    }
}
```

Adding follow intent-filter in activity "MainActivity", but still occured issue.

```xml
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```